# Watermark in the photo

Tags: python-3.x, save, python-imaging-library, watermark

I'm making a watermark in the photo. How to make a watermark for several photos at once? and How to save multiple photos at once? which loop should be and in which part of the code?

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageOps

def watermark_text(input_image_path,
                   output_image_path,
                   text, pos):
    photo = Image.open(input_image_path)

    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)

    white = (3, 8, 12)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/Roboto-Regular.ttf", 150)
    drawing.text(pos, text, fill=white, font=font)
    photo.show()
    photo.save(output_image_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = 'new7093.JPG'
    watermark_text(img, '11112.JPG',
                   text='sportves.ru',
                   pos=(300,500))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using multiprocessing.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os

img_list = os.listdir('path-to-image')
output_img_list = [i +'.output' for i in img_list]
text='sportves.ru'
pos=(300,500)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(watermark_text, input_image_path, output_image_path, text, pos) 
                        for input_image_path, output_image_path 
                           in zip(img_list, output_img_list)
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is should work). Replace a save path and append images to put watermarks.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont


def watermark_text(input_image_path,
                   output_image_path,
                   text, pos):
    global new_images
    photo = Image.open(input_image_path)

    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)

    white = (3, 8, 12)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/Roboto-Regular.ttf", 150)
    drawing.text(pos, text, fill=white, font=font)
    photo.show()
    new_images.append(photo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    images = ['new7093.JPG', 'something.phg']  # list of photos without watermark
    new_images = []  # list of photos with watermark
    for img in images:
        watermark_text(img, '11112.JPG',
                       text='sportves.ru',
                       pos=(300, 500))
    new_images[0].save(r'C:\Users\You\Desktop', save_all=True,
                       append_images=new_images[1:])  # replace by you path
```